# Couldn't connect to the Docker daemon on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, docker

Im trying to deploy an app on google cloud, just following https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world#running_hello_world tutorial, but everytime I run:

```
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

I got a message error:

```
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH key pair.
DEBUG: Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'compute', 'copy_files']
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://104.197.75.48:2376,
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=tmpurmvdk, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=True
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 104.197.75.48
DEBUG: Failed to connect to Docker daemon due to an SSL problem:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

am I missing something?

Comment: What does the IP address of your DOCKER_HOST variable signify? What steps did you go through in the tutorial, exactly? What kind of system are you on? What is `tmpurmvdk`?